# Linear equation with random values

Tags: linear-equation

I would like to insert random values from a lognormal distribution into a linear equation. The equation is:

```
y = 2/(9x) + 8
```

...and `x` shall take random values from the distribution

```
exp(rnorm(100, m=-2.59625, sd=0.5852539))
```

How do I generate the distribution of `y`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the code you provided should pretty much do what you're describing:

```
x <- exp(rnorm(100, m=-2.59625, sd=0.5852539))
y <- 2 / (9*x) + 8
```